# Apache POI HWPF, replacing text in .doc documents fails

Tags: java, open-source, ms-word, ms-office, apache-poi

I try to write down the result of the POI unit test at: [code here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/testcases/org/apache/poi/hwpf/usermodel/TestRangeReplacement.java?view=co), by adding the line

```
daDoc.write(new FileOutputStream("C:\\wordtest.doc"));
```

to the end of the method **testRangeReplacementAll**. The new document is corrupt when I try to open it with word 2003.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I would at least try to narrow this down, since that test does a number of things.

1. Can you open the original file in Word 2003 ?
2. can you open the file and immediately resave as another without doing any replacements. Does that open in Word 2003 ?
3. can you perform one replacement at least ?

Comment: I can only replace text which has an equal length to the placeholder. Means ${xy} can be replaced with 12345 and not with 1234 or 123456

Comment: Can you open the original file in Word 2003 ? << yes 
can you open the file and immediately resave as another without doing any replacements. Does that open in Word 2003 ? << i can open the original file. The replace result can't be opened.

I use the .doc file from the JUnit test case: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/testcases/org/apache/poi/hwpf/data/testRangeReplacement.doc?view=co

Like I said, the test went fine but the result can't be opened if i save it to a new .doc file.